# Steam API: How to query a server to get server info (not using A2S)?

Tags: api, steam, steamworks-api

I would like to know how to use the Steamworks Web API to query a server to get information (server name, game, map, players, etc.). I know that using the A2S query (https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries) can give that information, but I would like to know if it is possible using the Steamworks Web API instead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With IGameServersService/GetServerList. Here is an example:

```
https://api.steampowered.com/IGameServersService/GetServerList/v1/?key=API_KEY&filter=addr\YOUR.IP.ADRESS:PORT
```

For example, to get the map of a Garry's Mod server, you can try the following (code example is in PHP):

```
    $url = "https://api.steampowered.com/IGameServersService/GetServerList/v1/?key=API_KEY&filter=addr\185.254.99.6:27015";
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $table2 = json_decode($json, true);
    $table = $table2["response"]["servers"][0];
    $mapname = $table['map'];
```

Comment: The key can be generated here: `https://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey`